# C++ / C: Move Directory to Another Location

Tags: c, linux, file, unix, directory

I want to move the contents of one directory to another. I specify the source and destination directories via command line arguments. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void move_dir(FILE *src, FILE *dest) {
    int c = getc(src);
    while(getc(src)!=EOF) {
        putc(c,dest);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE *src=fopen(argv[1]);
    FILE *dest=fopen(argv[2]);
    while(--argc>0) {
        if(src!=NULL && dest!=NULL) {
            move_dir(src,dest);
        }
    }
    fclose(src);
    fclose(dest);
    return 0;
}
```

For example:

```
./a.out /Folder1/Folder2/Source /Folder1
```

This will move the folder called Source inside of Folder1. However when I execute this code it doesn't work. It compiles just fine with g++ and no errors when running but it just doesn't move anything at all. Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Comment: You should get the habit to compile with `g++ -Wall -g`

Comment: Do you want to make the equivalent of `mv` command? What about directories on different file systems?

Comment: Did you read http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/ ?

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** This is referring to the original post, which read `FILE * src = opendir( argv[1] );`.

The function `opendir()` returns a `DIR *`, which is quite different from a `FILE *` (and cannot be used as a parameter to `getc()` / `putc()`.

You have to read directory entries from that `DIR *` using `readdir()`, which will yield a filename, *then* copying that file using that information.

**Edit:** This is referring to the updated post.

You don't use file functions (`fopen()`, `getc()` etc.) on directories. The way to go is `opendir()` followed by `readdir()`, then acting on the yielded filenames.

I don't really know why `fopen()` on a directory actually returns a non-null pointer. Personally, I consider this a design flaw, as the operations possible on `FILE *` are not defined for directories. I would stay *well* clear of this construct.

---

Generally speaking, you should *read* the documentation (man page) of the functions you are using, not (wrongly) assuming things about them. And while you are at it, check return values, too - they might tell you why things don't work as expected.

Comment: But you should use `opendir` to read a directory, then act on each entry there.

Comment: @CharlieYabben: You cannot `fopen()` a directory, which brings me right back to "check the return values".

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Ah okay so I need to do opendir first then do individual file operations to move the files?

Comment: @CharlieYabben: That's what I wrote, yes.

Comment: Regarding my comment above on "you cannot `fopen()` a directory", I am quite surprised that, actually, you can. I don't know why `fopen()` returns non-NULL in this case, but IMHO it should...

Comment: Because one can `read(2)` a directory, even if the result is not well defined and may be file system specific.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Being able to do non-well-defined and file-system specific things only is a very good reason to have `fopen()` fail in the first place, but my tastes for API design have been known to differ from those common in the Unix world before. ;-)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Just checked the standard document again; it specifically refers to streams being connected to **files**, not directories (which are actually not mentioned at all). I.e., `fread()` is not defined on directories, and `read()` is done on an `open()` file descriptor, not an `fopen()` `FILE` handle. I.e., for all practical purposes, `fopen()` on a directory *should* fail.

Comment: It seems that on a recent Linux/Debian/AMD64 `fopen` a directory suceeds, but any read of it (thru `fscanf` or `fread`) would fail.